# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FinalBookingDate' property

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

Before starting, I know, this errors means that I should have defined the property FinalBookingDate, but just keep reading and you will understand my point of view.

The url is: http://bestbuyhotel1.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/ClientBackOffice_b.asmx?op=getBookingList
I was testing first with SoapUi, and I successfull get the list that I need:
[image: soapui]

And on php, I only can get this response: [image: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FinalBookingDate' property]

The SoapClient from php is:

```
$params = array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2, 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
$client = new \SoapClient('http://bestbuyhotel1.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/ClientBackOffice_b.asmx?wsdl', $params);
```

And then, the code to retrieve the data:

```
    /*
    $query = array(
        'InitialServiceDate' => '2015-01-20',
        'InitialBookingDate' => '2015-01-20',
        'FinalBookingDate' => '2015-01-20',
        'FinalServiceDate' => '2015-01-20',
        'CreationUserId' => 1338,
        'CityId' => 4166,
        'ServiceTypes' => array('eServiceType' => 'HOTEL')
    );
     */
    $query = array(
        'InitialBookingDate' => '2015-01-20',
        'ServiceTypes' => array('eServiceType' => 'HOTEL')
    );
    $args = new \stdClass;
    $args->credential = new \stdClass;
    $args->credential->UserName = $conn['userPass']['usr'];
    $args->credential->Password = $conn['userPass']['pass'];
    $args->searchBookingCriteria = new \stdClass;
    $args->searchBookingCriteria->InitialBookingDate = '2015-01-20';
    $args->searchBookingCriteria->ServiceTypes = new \stdClass;
    $args->searchBookingCriteria->ServiceTypes->eServiceType = 'HOTEL';

    //$args = array('credential'=>$credentials, 'searchBookingCriteria' => $query);
    $data = $conn['client']->getBookingList($args);
    print_r($data);
    exit;
```

As you can see, I tried 2 ways to send the $args to getBookingList, as far I know both of then is valid and yet both of then (with array or object) return the same error. On the code commented at first you can see that I tried to define all does properties that the web service asks but after defining all of then I get a empty result.

My question is, there is some extra param to define on SoapClient that I should do? Why the SoapUI can do it with success? What I have missing here?

Bonus: A print of SoapUI full screen with the default request including the optional params https://www.evernote.com/shard/s14/sh/fb5ac276-8147-4e09-95bb-afa0be66d7a6/d273441c74186bf1e600b42ab3303899/deep/0/SoapUI-5.0.0.png

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this more direct approach:

```
   try { 
    $params = array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2, 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8', 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
        $client = new SoapClient('http://bestbuyhotel1.cangooroo.net/ws/2013/ClientBackOffice_b.asmx?wsdl',$params); 
    } catch (SoapFault $E) { 
        echo $E->faultstring;
    }
    if ($client) { 
    $req_params = array('credential' => 
                            array('userName' => 'XXXXXXX',
                                  'Password' => 'XXXXXXX'),
                        'searchBookingCriteria' =>
                            array('BookingNumber' => array('int' => 'XXXXXXXXX'),
                                  'ServiceTypes' => array('eServiceType' => 'HOTEL'),
                                  'PassengerName'=> 'XXXXXXXX',
                                  'InitialBookingDate'=> '2015-01-16',
                                  'FinalBookingDate'=> '2015-01-16',
                                  'InitialServiceDate' => '2015-01-18',
                                  'FinalServiceDate' => '2015-01-18',
                                  'BookingStatus'=> array('eStatus' => 'ACTIVATED'),
                                  'PaymentStatus'=> array('ePaymentStatus' => 'Payed'),
                                  'CreationUserId'=> 'XXX',
                                  'CityId'=> 'XXXX',
                                  'ExternalReference'=> '')
        );
    $response = $client->__soapCall('getBookingList',array($req_params));
    var_dump($response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (and add) this approach:

```
$args->searchBookingCriteria->FinalBookingDate = '2015-01-22';
$args->searchBookingCriteria->InitialServiceDate = '2015-01-22';
$args->searchBookingCriteria->FinalServiceDate = '2015-01-22';
$args->searchBookingCriteria->CreationUserId = 'abc';
$args->searchBookingCriteria->CityId = 'abc';
```

Comment: This is like what is on array commented, but tried now to and I get the same response as expected, empty result: stdClass Object
(
    [getBookingListResult] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)

Comment: ok, didn't know that because in your code above it's commented out. I've no access to this particular webservice so I'm not able to reproduce it.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to check the difference with wireshark now. The incredible support from that webservice just says is working and the problem is with you app :@ I know that it is, but really, not even then have a clue? Annoying.